# azurite container not exposing ssl

Tags: docker, ssl, azurite

I'm trying to setup azurite using these [instructions](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/blob/main/README.md), I see a number of others have been successful with this.  I need to configure SSL (and eventually oauth) for my client app testing.  The azurite container works fine without SSL, but when SSL is activated my client can't connect because the container isn't exposing the certificate.

I used mkcert to create the certificate.  This is my docker-compose file.  I'm mounting /certs and /data from my host.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: "azurite"
    hostname: azurite
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10001:10001"
      - "10002:10002" 
    command: "azurite --oauth basic --cert /certs/127.0.0.1.pem --key /certs/127.0.0.1-key.pem --debug /logs/azurite-debug.log"      
    volumes:
        - ./azurite-store:/data
        - ./certs:/certs
        - ./azurite-logs:/logs
```

Using openssl inside the container shows;
[image: openssl inside container]

That's the cert I expect from mkcert & it's mounted as per the compose file.

From my laptop, openssl shows the following;
[image]
[image]

And there ends the fun!  Why is the cert visible on the url inside the container, but not from the outside?  I can't see anything in the compose file that would control if a cert is being exposed or not - I'm reasonably sure docker doesn't work like that - it's only exposing the tcp/ip layer to my laptop.

If I stop the container, port 10000 isn't reachable, start it and it opens so I don't think it's another process that I'm connecting to by mistake.  Also, the fact that I get a connection means that it's not a connectivity issue.

Anyone got any thoughts on this one - it's weird!  "Cert filtering" if I can call it that is certainly a new one!?

Answer (score 5):

A little time away from the keyboard always helps

Looks like this is an application binding issue.  Looks like node had bound to loopback (with the cert) and while docker had mapped the port out to my host, at an application layer node wasn't listening with a cert on that port.  Changing blobHost to 0.0.0.0 allowed node to bind to all ip addresses on the container which in turn meant the cert was visible on the mapped port.

The docker-compose "command" becomes;

```
command: "azurite --oauth basic -l /data --cert /certs/127.0.0.1.pem --key /certs/127.0.0.1-key.pem --debug /logs/azurite-debug.log --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --tableHost 0.0.0.0"
```

I also found that despite mapping /data to a local volume I was loosing the blob containers on a container restart.  Adding "-l /data" solved that one too.